# Elastic search get query not taking updated information

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement to update user info and get the update userinfo after update. Both the queries are working. But when i call /get immediately after update query it is not fetching the updated info. When i put a timeout of 2ms its correctly fetching updated info. Am new to elastic search, i dont know how its caching updated info, is there any way to get the updated info immediately in get query?

update query

```
    var user = {};
user.first_name = "John updated" 
db.update({
            index: config.index_name,
            type: 'user',
            id: req.body.user_id,
            body: {
                doc: user
            }
        }, function (err, resp) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
             db.search({
                index: config.index_name,
                type: 'user',
                body:  {
                    "query": {
                        "match": {
                            "_id": req.body.user_id
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, function (err, resp) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                var data = {};       
                    data.creator_name = resp.hits.hits[0]._source.first_name 
                    // Here am not getting update first name "John updated" instead of getting John
            });
});
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What API  are you using? And by the way, you seem to be doing search rather than get.

Comment: @Ashalynd Thank you for you quick comment. Yes am using search query to get updated info. Could you please let me know is there any alternative query to get info. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `Refresh` parameter as described here :
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html

This will make sure the updated document will be available immediately within a search result.

Hope this helps !